# how to compare bitbucket x-hub-signature in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket

how to compare the Bit bucket X-Hub-Signature in Jenkins? I have added a secret to the repository, and I am able to see the X-Hub-Signature in Jenkins. I am calculating the SHA256 of the payload and secret, but it's giving a different result in my Python script.

What is the optimal way to achieve this?